# Missing image from Rotativa PDF file

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

We are using [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/) to save a permanent PDF copy of the page on the web server. Here is the ASP.NET MVC 4 code to build and save it:

```
 var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { orderId = orderValidated.orderID }) { FileName = filePath };

 var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

 // writes only if the file does not exist, we need to keep first authentic print of it.
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) == false)
 {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, binary);
 }
```

We use a specific 'css' file for printing in the page `<head>` section:

```
<head>
  <link media=all href="/Content/invoice.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
  <link media=print href="/Content/printInv.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>      
</head>
```

The 'css' print version contains:

```
#logo {background: url(/assets/images/logo-plain.gif) no-repeat; height: 56px}
```

and the *.gif image is missing from the PDF document (on screen is present).

Any idea on the reason why it's missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Rotativa has problems with gif images. Try using jpg or png.

Answer (score 2):

I'm think this is an issue with Rotativa.

What I did to solve was insert the background image inline using the image tag then use css to position it:

```
   #bg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/background-image.jpg")" id="bg" />
```

Answer (score -1):

"<img height=200 width=200 src="/ProductImages/" + rd["ItemCode"].ToString() + ".jpg" />"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32991942)